# Which order of joins is faster?

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

I'm looking at a MS SQL Server database which was developed by a company that is an expert at database design (or so I'm told) and I noticed a curious pattern of JOINs/indexes. It's upside down from what I would have done, so I wonder if it has some performance benefits (the DB is fairly big).

The table structure (simplified pseudocode) is:

Table JOBS (about 1K rows):

- job_id [int, primary key]
- server_id [int, foreign key]
- job_name [string]

Table JOB_HISTORY (about 17M rows):

- history_id [int, primary key]
- job_id [int, foreign key]
- server_id [int, foreign key]
- job_start [datetime]
- job_duration [int]

Note the denormalization where the `server_id` is in both tables.

What they did is:

```
select
    t1.job_name, t2.job_start, t2.job_duration
from
    JOBS t1
inner join 
    JOB_HISTORY t2 on (t1.job_id = t2.job_id and t1.server_id = t2.server_id)
where
    t1.server_id = @param_server_id
    and t2.job_start >= @param_from
    and t2.job_start <= @param_to
```

And they have indexes:

- JOBS => (server_id)
- JOB_HISTORY => (job_id, server_id, job_start)

In other words, when they select the rows, they first filter the jobs from `JOBS` table and then look up the relevant `JOB_HISTORY` entries. This is what the DB is forced to do, because of the indexes.

What I would have done it is the bottom-up version:

```
select
    t1.job_name, t2.job_start, t2.job_duration
from
    JOB_HISTORY t2
inner join 
    JOBS t1 on (t1.job_id = t2.job_id)
where
    t2.server_id = @param_server_id
    and t2.job_start >= @param_from
    and t2.job_start <= @param_to
```

And a single index:

- JOB_HISTORY => (server_id, job_start)

So, basically, I directly select the relevant rows from the large `JOB_HISTORY` and then just look for the attached data from the `JOBS` table.

Is there a reason to prefer one over the other?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - No, it will not, because of the different indexes.

Comment: What do the plans say?

Comment: I'd like to show the plans, but I don't want to disturb the actual database  by creating/dropping indexes from a 17M record table. Especially since I'm a subcontractor that only needs to do a few small fixes, and all DB modifications go through them. However, when it comes to 17M rows, doing a full scan is madness, and the DB know this. Obviously it will try to use whichever index is available.

Comment: Well, without being able to actually see which plan is being used, it's all pure conjecture really

Comment: @LesH - Well, isn't there some sort of "rule of thumb" for such cases? This isn't the first time I see this. So far I thought this simply reflected the way people's minds worked (first select the jobs, then their histories), but this time I have a reason to believe that this was written by someone more knowledgeable than me.

Comment: Good question but why do you need to drop indexes to view the plan?  If you place both versions of the query in one window and press Ctrl+L SSMS will show you two execution plans, which you can compare.  Apologies if I've missed something here.  You may well find the optimizer delivers two identical plans.

Comment: @destination-data - Hmm, well, OK, you're right - no need to drop the index. But I'd still need to create a new index on a 17M row table, and that would likely freeze the server for a few dozen minutes.

Comment: Adding an index on 17M rows isn't all that bad. Depending on the data (how many pages need to be read, how many fields (and what size are they) need to be ordered etc...) and the hardware (faster I/O and more CPU's are golden here) this could take between a couple of seconds and a couple of minutes. Surely not 'dozens'. FYI: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177442%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Well, I was a bit bored so thought I'd re-create this for you. First setup (I'm using a numbers table to generate about 1K and 17M rows, of course, this is all random data and doesn't represent your system :) I'm also assuming theres a clustered index on each table, even though you imply you wouldn't have one.

```
    USE TempDB;
    GO
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Jobs;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Job_History;

    CREATE TABLE #Jobs
        (
         job_id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
        ,server_id INT
        ,job_name VARCHAR(50)
        );

    CREATE TABLE #Job_History
        (
         history_id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
        ,job_id INT
        ,server_id INT
        ,job_start DATETIME DEFAULT SYSDATETIME()
        ,job_duration INT DEFAULT ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 5000
        );
    GO

    INSERT  INTO #Jobs
            SELECT  server_id = N.n
                   ,job_name = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID())
            FROM    DBA.Dim.Numbers N
            WHERE   n < 1000;

    INSERT  INTO #JOB_HISTORY
            ( job_id
            ,server_id
            )
            SELECT  job_id = j1.job_id
                   ,server_id = j1.server_id
            FROM    #Jobs j1
                    CROSS JOIN DBA.Dim.Numbers n
            WHERE   n < 17000;
```

Now, case 1 (their way)

```
    DROP INDEX IF EXISTS Idx_Job_hist ON #Job_History;
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX Idx_Job_Hist ON #Job_History (job_id, server_id, job_start);

    DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
    DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS

    DECLARE @param_server_id INT = 1234
    DECLARE @param_from INT = 500
    DECLARE @param_to INT = 1000

    select
        t1.job_name, t2.job_start, t2.job_duration
    from
        #JOBS t1
    inner join 
        #JOB_HISTORY t2 on (t1.job_id = t2.job_id and t1.server_id = t2.server_id)
    where
        t1.server_id = @param_server_id
        and t2.job_start >= @param_from
        and t2.job_start <= @param_to;
```

And Case 2 (your way)

```
    DROP INDEX IF EXISTS Idx_Job_hist ON #Job_History;
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX Idx_Job_Hist ON #Job_History (server_id, job_start);

    select
        t1.job_name, t2.job_start, t2.job_duration
    from
        #JOB_HISTORY t2
    inner join 
        #JOBS t1 on (t1.job_id = t2.job_id)
    where
        t2.server_id = @param_server_id
        and t2.job_start >= @param_from
        and t2.job_start <= @param_to;
```

And the (totally non-conclusive, because my system isn't your system...) results:

Their plan:
[image]

Your Plan:
[image]

The costs from your plan were much higher overall.

But then this is a rather artificial exercise to just prove the point - run the plans, the answer is -  it depends.

(Thanks for the excuse to play with this, it was fun :)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer here is that it doesn't really matter in what order you `JOIN` the tables. SQL is one of those languages where you tell the server what you want, not so much what you want it to do (**). (AKA a so-called [declarative language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming)).

The reason we are seeing different Query Plans for the two versions of your query is that they are not exactly the same. In the first one there is a requirement that `server_id` is identical in both tables, while in the second version this is no longer mentioned. `t1.server_id` can be anything there. If you re-add this requirement you'll notice that the query plans will be identical and that the server will do exactly the same thing 'under the hood' for either query.

FYI: Building on Les H's answer I took the liberty of checking what kind of index MSSQL would suggest here and not-surprisingly it came up with

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_test
ON [dbo].[Job_History] ([server_id],[job_start])
INCLUDE ([job_id],[job_duration])
```

FYI:

- without the index, each query took about 1500ms to run
- creating the index took about 20 seconds
- with the index, each query takes about 200ms to run

(**: Yes, I'm aware that you can 'direct' what happens under the hood by means of HINTS, but experience shows that those should only be a last resort when the QO no longer is able to make sense of things. In most cases, when the statistics are up-to-date and the data layout is not extremely exotic, the Query Optimizer is ridiculously smart about finding the best way to get you the data you asked for.)